# How to get rid of web ads that show what you've looked at on Amazon?

Tags: amazon, ads, cookies

It seems now that anytime I "shop" online, i.e., look at anything in a shopping site such as Amazon, ads for that thing I looked at show up everywhere. For instance, I happened to click on ladybugs and now I have ladybugs showing up everywhere. These things last for weeks even if I actually buy the thing! I'm sure they have something to do with cookies.

Is there anyway to remove that cookie without disabling my ability to shop on Amazon?

Comment: If it's mostly amazon ads that are annoying you then you can turn off your amazon browsing history as well as _personalized ads_: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/12005/how-to-prevent-amazon-from-tracking-your-browsing-and-recording-your-visits-to-3rd-party-sites/ — another annoying thing is that those settings are only for the current browser..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try blocking Third-Party Cookies. Most of these [retargeting ads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_retargeting) are run by scripts that won't be able to drop their own cookies if they aren't from the same domain as the site you're visiting.

There are a few more things you can do, depending on your choice of browser. Adblock-type plugins (available for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/)) will often block the scripts that try to drop these cookies, and plugins like DoNotTrackMe & Ghostery try to block even more for you.

Firefox third-party cookie settings:
[image: Firefox third-party cookie settings]

Chrome third-party cookie settings:
[image: Chrome third-party cookie settings]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize (obviously) that it was possible to ignore 3rd party cookies- I assume these are those that are not from the site I am requesting.

Comment: Blocking third-party cookies might potentially cause problems with some (badly written?) websites which rely on their own cookies created from different domains. I.e. if you notice you cannot login to a site then check if enabling third-party cookies might be causing it.