# Facebook is stealing my eBay search history

Tags: facebook, ebay

I have recently noticed that when I search for something on eBay, I start seeing ads of similar items in my Facebook homepage. I suspect Facebook is somehow stealing my search history.

Is there a way I can block Facebook from doing this? I am sure I can do this without permanently deleting my Facebook account so I just want to give one last try before I actually go ahead with that idea (and I am on the verge of doing this).

Comment: Related question: [How to get rid of web ads that show what you've looked at on Amazon?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/43708/26981)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind this could be advertisement [(Behavioural) Retargeting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_retargeting).

Cookies on eBay may enable advertisers to show the similar or the same item again on Facebook.

See more infomation on:
[FBX: How to Create Retargeted Facebook Ads with PerfectAudience](http://www.jonloomer.com/2013/05/06/facebook-fbx-perfectaudience/)

As Karthik VU pointed out, you can use [Privacy mode / Private browsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_browsing) to limit leakage of your browsing trail.

Safari — Private Browsing
Google Chrome — Incognito
Internet Explorer — InPrivate Browsing
Mozilla Firefox — Private Browsing

Answer (score 2):

- Delete your cookies after visiting eBay/Facebook;
- Block 3rd party cookies;
- Block/remove from cache pixels.gif [(web bugs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bugs);
- Use your browser in incognito mode;
- [Block/Delete Flash cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object);
- Browse in https (set browser to https everywhere).
- Revise/Fix you 'privacy settings' on facebook and ebay pages.
- Do NOT set your browser settings to 'Tell websites to not track'.

You can also try to use a proxy like Tor onion.

And, keep this in mind : if it's free, you are the product.

Answer (score 1):

Use eBay in incognito mode or keep clearing cookies every time! It doesn't steal your browser history. eBay leaves cookies in your computer and Facebook uses these to make your experience better. You need not worry about this.

Comment: Actually I do need to worry as I was under the impression that cookies from one site cannot be read by any other site. If facebook can read my search cookies, they can very well read my session cookies too.